# Cancel a Step Function in the Wait step

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I need a step function that waits 2 days before processing a request. Within that two day period it's possible for a user to cancel the request with a follow up request. Is this achievable with step functions.

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly possible to stop a currently executing step function.

Using the AWS CLI as an example, you can call `aws step functions stop-execution` with an exeuction-arn:

```
$ aws step-function stop-execution --execution-arn <value>
    [--error <value>]
    [--cause <value>]
    [--cli-input-json <value>]
    [--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/stepfunctions/stop-execution.html

The stop-execution function is also available in the various AWS SDKs and client libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Best implementation for this use case would be WaitForTask token.
Your Step function could wait for one year before it gets timed out.

whenever your user cancel, you can use tasktoken to fail the workflow. In this way you won't have to deal with executionid. infact you can use tasktoken to manage this workflow.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-lambda-orchestration.html

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to figure out if I could do the same thing. The API reference docs suggest we can.

If it's as simple as cancelling the step, then we can do the following:

1. User to trigger a Lambda from the front-end.
2. The Lambda can use listExecutions
   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_ListExecutions.html)
   to find the executionArn associated with the name.
3. We can then use StopExecution
   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StopExecution.html)
   to cancel the execution.

If we want to skip the WAIT (ie, reduce the waiting time to zero), then it might be as simple as using the StartExecution method of the API - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html . This is assuming that the State Machine creates the executionArn before the WAIT countdown starts (rather than waiting until after the WAIT countdown to create the ARN).